# Split two objects from one

Tags: powershell

I've imported an objects thats actually two different objects to a single variable:

```
PS> $object | gm

TypeName: Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
...

TypeName: System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
...
```

I can only access information from the first object. Is there a way to split this into two variables based on TypeName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this question I assume you know the types in advance, but you do not necessarily know the order they will appear in the array `$object`.

The code below will extract the items of each known type from th list:

```
$customObject = $object | ? { $_.GetType().Name -like "*PSCustomObject" }
$certficate = $object | ? { $_.GetType().Name -like "*X509Certificate2" }
```

Comment: In this case I do know the input order but, yes this worked thank you!

Answer (score 9):

**PowerShell supports *destructuring / parallel assignments***, officially known as **[*multiple assignment*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.1#assigning-multiple-variables)**.

**If you know the order** of the objects contained in collection `$object`:

```sh
$custObj, $cert = $object # $custObj receives $object[0], $cert the rest.
```

`$custObj` will receive the 1st object contained in `$object`, and `$cert` the rest - which in the case of a 2-element collection is the 2nd element (as a scalar; if the collection had more elements, `$cert` would receive an *array* (`[object[]]`)).

Otherwise, in **PowerShell v4+**, you can use the **`.Where()` collection method to split a collection in *two* based on a *condition***:

```
$cert, $custObj = $objects.Where(
 { $_ -is [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2] },
 'Split'
)
```

Comment: I looked over it. It would be so cool if it would've worked like in js. I would like to be able to do something like `foreach($a, $b in $values) {}`

Comment: @Vivere, that doesn't actually work in PowerShell, but I don't think it's needed; however, what would be nice is if _parallel collections_ could be enumerated this way - see [GitHub proposal #14732](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14732).

Comment: Why wouldn't it be needed? For example, if you intend to interpolate strings inside that foreach, you would write `"$($obj.Property)"` instead of `"${Property}"`.  It would be cleaner imo. A way of iterating multiple collections would be cool, yes, like zip in python.

Comment: @Vivere, The proposed parallel-collection enumeration syntax, if it gets implemented, would clash with your proposal. Assuming you're looking for what you proposed [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/7394#issuecomment-810313287), you'd therefore need _additional syntax_ to indicate per-object property destructuring. I'm not saying it wouldn't be useful, but I personally see less of a need for it. If you feel strongly enough about this, I encourage you to create a feature request at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues